# NestJS: wrap 3rd party decorator & setMetaData in order to use Reflector to check annotation

Tags: nestjs

I am using NestJS to implement a project with TypeScript.

I am using a 3rd party library which provide a decorator called `Protected`, I can use the decorator to annotate my controller method:

```
@Protected()
myFunc(){
  ...
}
```

I have a `Guard`, in which I want to check whether the annotation is there inside my `MyGuard` class. I tried:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const value = this.reflector.get('Protected', context.getHandler());
    console.log(`VALUE: ${metaValue}`);
    ...
  }
}
```

The log message shows me `VALUE: undefined`.  I read the NestJS doc, there is an example of using `setMetadata()` and then in Guard method use the metadata key to retrieve metadata to check if the annotation is there. However, this is a 3rd party decorator, there is no information for me whether they use any metadata key.

So, I come up with a workaround, I create my own custom decorator which wraps the 3rd party `Protected` decorator & use my decorator instead on controller method:

```
import {Protected} from '3rd-party-lib'
import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';

export const MyProtected = () => {
    Protected();
    SetMetadata(IS_PROTECTED, true);
}
```

But now, the annotation on controller method raises error:

```
/**
ERROR: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
  This expression is not callable.
    Type 'void' has no call signatures.ts(1241)
**/
@MyProtected()
myFunc(){
  ...
}
```

My questions:

1. Is there a way to use `Reflector` to check whether the 3rd party annotation is presented in the controller method inside `MyGuard` ?
2. If there is no way without using `setMetadata` & since I don't know what metadata key to check due to 3rd party library. How can I `setMetadata` myself in my custom decorator in order to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 4):

Why not use [Nest's `applyDecorators`](https://docs.nestjs.com/custom-decorators#decorator-composition) so you can compose the decorator out of several decorators?

```js
export const MyProtected = () => applyDecorators(
  Protected(),
  SetMetadata(IS_PROTECTED, true)
);
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks great. I am newbie in NestJS , didn't know it. I will try it tomorrow